# Could not read memory pymem

Tags: python, memory, types

I am trying to overwrite the float value at a specific memory address using a pointer address. I have the base address of the application and the offsets which lead me to the location of my float I want to overwrite. Although I cant get it to work. Any ideas what im doing wrong? Exception happens when the `unlimitedHunger()` function is called.

```
from pymem import *
from pymem.process import *
pm = pymem.Pymem("xxx.exe")
gameModule = module_from_name(pm.process_handle, "xxx").lpBaseOfDll

def getPtrAdrr(base, offsets):
    addr = pm.read_long(base)
    for i in offsets:
        if i != offsets[-1]:
            addr = pm.read_long(addr + i)
    return addr + offsets[-1]

def godMode():
    return None

def unlimitedHunger():
    while True:
        pm.write_float(getPtrAdrr(gameModule + 0x08959C68,[0x410, 0xC8, 0X3B0, 0X4C8, 0X158,0XAF0]), 100.00)


def unlimitedStatPoints():
    return None

def duplicationWindow():
    return None
```

```
TypeError: cannot be converted to pointer
pm.write_float(getPtrAdrr(gameModule + 0x08959C68,[0x410, 0xC8, 0X3B0, 0X4C8, 0X158, 0XAF0]),   100.00)
```

the arguments passed to `getPtrAdrr(base, offsets)` should result in a valid pointer and overwrite the current value to 100.0

after changing to read_long from read_float here is the stack

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jkmal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pymem\__init__.py", line 832, in read_long
    value = pymem.memory.read_long(self.process_handle, address)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\jkmal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pymem\memory.py", line 421, in read_long
    return read_ctype(handle, address, ctypes.c_long())
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\jkmal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pymem\memory.py", line 148, in read_ctype
    raise pymem.exception.WinAPIError(error_code)
pymem.exception.WinAPIError: Windows api error, error_code: 299

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\jkmal\Desktop\Overpal v1\Overpal\main.py", line 205, in <module>
    onceloaded.run()
  File "c:\Users\jkmal\Desktop\Overpal v1\Overpal\onceloaded.py", line 6, in run
    userinterface.mainMenu()
  File "c:\Users\jkmal\Desktop\Overpal v1\Overpal\userinterface.py", line 16, in mainMenu
    hunger_Checkbox = customtkinter.CTkCheckBox(root, text="Fill Hunger" ,variable=hungerBoxStatus, onvalue="On", offvalue="Off", command=utility.unlimitedHunger())
                                                                                                                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\jkmal\Desktop\Overpal v1\Overpal\utility.py", line 21, in unlimitedHunger
    pm.write_float(getPtrAdrr(gameModule + 0x08959C68,[0x410, 0xC8, 0X3B0, 0X4C8, 0X158, 0XAF0]), 100.00)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\jkmal\Desktop\Overpal v1\Overpal\utility.py", line 11, in getPtrAdrr
    addr = pm.read_long(addr + i)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\jkmal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pymem\__init__.py", line 834, in read_long
    raise pymem.exception.MemoryReadError(address, struct.calcsize('l'), e.error_code)
pymem.exception.MemoryReadError: Could not read memory at: 717079632, length: 4 - GetLastError: 299
```

Comment: `getPtrAddr()` should be using `pm.read_long()` or something like that - floats are completely unsuitable for use as an address.  Only at the very end of your chain of pointers with offsets do you have an address that actually contains a float.

Comment: @jasonharper  I changed to pm.read_long and pm.read_longlong and both result in this
Could not read memory at: 717079632, length: 4 - GetLastError: 299

Comment: Please post the full traceback.

Comment: @Barmar I added the full stack to the OP, sorry im new to stack overflow postings

Comment: The traceback says `pm.read_long`, but the code snippet contains `pm.read_float`. Did you modify the code before grabbing the traceback?

Comment: Yes sorry I wrote above the trace I changed it to read_long based on jasonharpers suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by using ptypes finally! To jump from pointer to pointer you need to read pointer value. Instead of reading int, you can use "ptypes"

```
def getPointerAddress(base, offsets):
    remote_pointer = RemotePointer(pm.process_handle, base)
    for offset in offsets:
        if offset != offsets[-1]:
            remote_pointer = RemotePointer(pm.process_handle, remote_pointer.value + offset)
        else:
            return remote_pointer.value + offset
```